# Backbone.js: Logging a view instance only return el attribute

Tags: backbone.js

I have a button and a form. Initially, the form is hidden when AddMenuForm view is initialize.

I register a event for AddMenuButton so that when the button is clicked it would unhide the form.

However the code addMenuForm.$el.show() doesn't work. When I try to console log the addMenuForm, I get the el attribute of addMenuForm instead of a addMenuForm instance.

```
new App;
var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
         var addMenuButton = new AddMenuButton;
         var addMenuForm = new AddMenuForm;
    }
});

var AddMenuButton = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#addMenuButton',

    events: {
        'click': 'click'
    },

    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(addMenuForm);
        addMenuForm.$el.show();
    }
});

var AddMenuForm = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#addMenuForm',

    initialize: function() {
        this.$el.hide(); // hide the form
    }
})
```

Comment: I think, using `var` unreliable way in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this and it works normally

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Backbone.js</title>
  <script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="underscore.js"></script>
  <script src="backbone.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="demo">
<form method ="get" id="addMenuForm" >
<input type="text" value="test"/>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Check it out!"  />
</form>
<input type="button" name="button" value="show form" id="addMenuButton" />
</div>
<script>

var App = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : "demo",
    initialize: function() {
        addMenuForm = new AddMenuForm();
        addMenuButton = new AddMenuButton({addMenuForm: addMenuForm});

    }
});

var AddMenuButton = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : '#addMenuButton',

    initialize: function(options) {
        this.addMenuForm = options.addMenuForm;
    },

    events: {
        'click': 'click'
    },

    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(addMenuForm);
        addMenuForm.$el.show();
    }
});

var AddMenuForm = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    el : '#addMenuForm',

    initialize: function() {
        this.$el.hide(); // hide the form
    }
});
var  myApp = new App();

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume the ? is a typo. Anyway I tried you code but now it's not even registering my click event.

Comment: ? means `if(options) than ...`

Comment: Nothing happens. I tried to write an extra `console.log('test')` to make sure but same result.

Comment: @UlugbekKomilovich console.log(addMenuForm); needs to be console.log(this.addMenuForm);

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the scope. Your `AddMenuButton` class does not know the `addMenuForm` instance as this instance was created in the initialize method of `App`.

You could for example take out the instantiation of `addMenuForm` and do this inside of the initialize method of AddMenuButton.

```
var AddMenuButton = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#addMenuButton',

    initialize: function () {
       this.addMenuForm = new AddMenuForm
    },

    events: {
        'click': 'click'
    },

    click: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.addMenuForm);
        this.addMenuForm.$el.show();
    }
});
```

I did not try it but it should work that way.